# Set multiple router for same controller in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-router

How to set multiple router for the same controller,if we are facing with the different action in one controller?
I have two action in my controller services in admin module.
 
First action is manage and second is manageArticle
Here is my code

```
protected function _initRoutes(){
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $router = $this->getResource('FrontController')->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                        'admin/services/:actionType',
                        array('module' => 'admin',
                            'controller' => 'services',
                            'action' => 'manage'),
                        array('actionType' => '(add|edit)')
                    );

    $router->addRoute('services', $route);     

    $routeServiceArticle = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                        'admin/services/article/:actionType',
                        array('module' => 'admin',
                            'controller' => 'services',
                            'action' => 'manageArticle'),
                        array('actionType' => '(addArticle|editArticle)')
                    );

    $router->addRoute('services', $routeServiceArticle);      
}
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the routes different names, e.g.:

```
$router->addRoute('services', $route);

[...]

$router->addRoute('servicesArticle', $routeServiceArticle);
```

Then it should work.